# Send value of button to table cell in another html page

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I need help in sending the value of the button (yes, no or maybe) from the  `form.html` to the table cell "attending" in `table.html`.

If the user clicks the "Yes" button, the `yes` value will insert into the `attending` table cell. Same for the other buttons pressed on the `form.html` to the `table.html` page.

How would I implement this?

My `form.html`:

```
<form method="post" action="savedConnections.html" id="add">
    <p>Would you like to attend this event?</p>
    <button  class="btn btn-success" onclick="addValue();">Yes</button>
    <button  class="btn btn-info" onclick="addValue();">Maybe</button>
    <button  class="btn btn-danger" onclick="addValue();">No</button>
</form>
```

My `table.html`:

```
<div class="table">
    <table class="table" id="tableEdit">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Connections</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th id="attending">Attending?</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Releasing Sea Turtles back to the Ocean</td>
            <td>Volunteer Trips</td>
            <td class="r1"> </td>
            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="margin:5px;">Update</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="delete"  style="margin:5px;" onclick="deleteRow(this.parentNode.rowIndex)">
                    Delete </button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Learning about Sea Turtles</td>
            <td>Educational Programs</td>
            <td class="r2">  </td>
            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="margin:5px;">Update</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="delete"  style="margin:5px;" onclick="deleteRow(this.parentNode.rowIndex)">
                    Delete </button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Protect the Sea Turtles</td>
            <td>Fundraisers</td>
            <td class="r3"></td>
            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="margin:5px;">Update</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="delete"  style="margin:5px;" onclick="deleteRow(this.parentNode.rowIndex)">
                    Delete </button></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please show us what you tried already so that we can help you debug your code instead of writing it for you.

Comment: you can use the GET method. and furthermore, provide your code what you have tried?